# Undefined reference error to std::string and std::vector class methods

Tags: c++, std, undefined-reference

On compiling this code, gcc shows a strange log that has a bunch of undefined reference errors to various `std::vector` and `std::string` methods.

I absolutely have no idea of what is going on, and hence haven't tried much things.

code:

```cpp
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>

void subs(std::vector<std::string> container, std::string s) {
    if(std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), s) != container.end())

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        std::vector<char> splitted;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
            splitted.push_back(s[i]);

        container.erase(container.begin()+i);
        std::string newSub = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < splitted.size(); ++i)
            newSub.append(std::string(1, splitted[i]));

        container.push_back(newSub);
        subs(container, newSub);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "abcd";
    std::vector<std::string> vec;
    subs(vec, s);
    for(auto i: vec)
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
}
```

gcc logs this on the terminal window:

```
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `subs(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0xf4): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::length() const'
main.cpp:(.text+0x119): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator[](unsigned long)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1ad): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1c7): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x1d6): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x20e): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(unsigned long, char, std::allocator<char> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x257): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x263): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x272): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a7): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c9): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2d5): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x2ff): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x324): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x346): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a8): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3bf): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3cb): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x3ea): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x409): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x47e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x48c): undefined reference to `std::cout'
main.cpp:(.text+0x491): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x49b): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4a6): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4b2): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x4de): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x503): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x51d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x52e): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x54b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x58e): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
main.cpp:(.text+0x5a3): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_Vector_impl::~_Vector_impl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIcSaIcEE12_Vector_implD2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIcSaIcEE12_Vector_implD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_realloc_insert<char const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > >, char const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_]+0x1d7): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_]+0x238): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorIcSaIcEE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKcEEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPcS1_EEDpOT_]+0x240): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_realloc_insert<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_]+0x1ec): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_]+0x254): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_[_ZNSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE17_M_realloc_insertIJRKS5_EEEvN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS5_S7_EEDpOT_]+0x25c): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::_Vector_base<char, std::allocator<char> >::_Vector_impl::_Vector_impl()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt12_Vector_baseIcSaIcEE12_Vector_implC2Ev[_ZNSt12_Vector_baseIcSaIcEE12_Vector_implC5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorIcSaIcEE12_M_check_lenEmPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorIcSaIcEE12_M_check_lenEmPKc]+0x5b): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::construct<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE9constructIS6_JRKS6_EEEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE9constructIS6_JRKS6_EEEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x48): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >::_M_check_len(unsigned long, char const*) const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE12_M_check_lenEmPKc[_ZNKSt6vectorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESaIS5_EE12_M_check_lenEmPKc]+0x5b): undefined reference to `std::__throw_length_error(char const*)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE7destroyIS6_EEvPT_[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE7destroyIS6_EEvPT_]+0x18): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::deallocate(char*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE10deallocateEPcm[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE10deallocateEPcm]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<char>::__value, bool>::__type std::operator==<char>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_[_ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_]+0x1b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_[_ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_]+0x2a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_[_ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_]+0x3b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::size() const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_[_ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_]+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::data() const'
main.cpp:(.text._ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_[_ZSteqIcEN9__gnu_cxx11__enable_ifIXsrSt9__is_charIT_E7__valueEbE6__typeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIS3_St11char_traitsIS3_ESaIS3_EEESE_]+0x59): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::data() const'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE8allocateEmPKv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorIcE8allocateEmPKv]+0x38): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x2c): undefined reference to `std::__throw_bad_alloc()'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEmPKv[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE8allocateEmPKv]+0x3c): undefined reference to `operator new(unsigned long)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::deallocate(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, unsigned long)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE10deallocateEPS6_m[_ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEE10deallocateEPS6_m]+0x1c): undefined reference to `operator delete(void*)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void std::_Destroy<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt8_DestroyINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEvPT_[_ZSt8_DestroyINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEvPT_]+0x14): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* std::__copy_move<true, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt11__copy_moveILb1ELb0ESt26random_access_iterator_tagE8__copy_mIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_EET0_T_SB_SA_[_ZNSt11__copy_moveILb1ELb0ESt26random_access_iterator_tagE8__copy_mIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEES9_EET0_T_SB_SA_]+0x4b): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >* std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy<std::move_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>(std::move_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>, std::move_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_[_ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_]+0x77): undefined reference to `__cxa_begin_catch'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_[_ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_]+0x8f): undefined reference to `__cxa_rethrow'
main.cpp:(.text._ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_[_ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEES9_EET0_T_SC_SB_]+0x97): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o: In function `void std::_Construct<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZSt10_ConstructINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEJS5_EEvPT_DpOT0_[_ZSt10_ConstructINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEJS5_EEvPT_DpOT0_]+0x3d): undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&)'
/tmp/cchWhwOD.o:(.data.rel.local.DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you linked with gcc not g++, dont you?

Comment: How did you compile the code?

Comment: By the way, unless you start using some references, that whole function does nothing useful

Comment: @Slava, yes I was using gcc.

Comment: @Nilesh read the dup it clearly explains why you have this issue and why you should use g++ instead